Why is my Socket.io implementation not working in Strapi 4.17?
I am trying to implement socket.io into my strapi project and It doesn't work and I don't know why.
I implemented bootstrap.js into config/functions folder.
module.exports = async ({ strapi }) => {
  console.log('Bootstrap loaded') 
  require('../../src/socket-server')({ strapi }) 
}

I impleneted socket-server.js in src/socket-server.js
const { Server } = require('socket.io')

module.exports = ({ strapi }) => {
  
  const io = new Server(strapi.server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*', 
    },
  })

  strapi.io = io 

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('A user connected:', socket.id)

   
    socket.on('sendMessage', data => {
      console.log('Message received:', data)
      io.emit('message', data) 
    })

   
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('User disconnected:', socket.id)
    })
  })
}


and I created a hook for my messages
module.exports = {
  async afterCreate(event) {
    const { result } = event

    
    const io = strapi.io 
    if (io) {
      io.emit('message', result)
    }
  },
}


but when I try to run a code, bootstrap.js doesn't even console log a string. I was trying everything, but I was a little bit lost.

Why exactly you don’t want to use plugin-io? It’s quite flexible (can just provide you with connection).

config/functions is not a folder where you implement bootstrap. Bootstrap is implemented in src/index.js
